# How to choose TCP/IP port numbers?

Tags: debian, port, tcp

We are going to install a range of software on a Debian Linux installation. Because we run the same software (such as Celery) several times, we need to use port numbers different than the standard Debian port numbers chosen by default (because we can't run more than one instance of a server with the same port, and thus using the standard port number for all servers would fail).

How to choose TCP/IP port numbers for server software we run in such a way that they don't clash with "standard" Debian port numbers?

In Debian are there any ranges of port numbers dedicated (so that they wouldn't clash with "standard" that is used by default port numbers) for servers configured by users?

Note that we run (at least some of) our software not as root, so we can't use ports below 1024.

Comment: while it was not me that downvoted, i guess the reason is that this question is inappropriate for [so], as it is not related to programming. a better place would be [sf] or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.debian.user/_5f8qSy8E8g/TYbuQEeqAQAJ

You can try using 61001 through 65534 as 
a range that's fairly unlikely to be assigned to anything, assuming 
nobody changes net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range, and with the knowledge that 
using such a range could cause interoperability problems if some of the 
servers use other operating systems (that might use that range for 
ephemeral ports).

Comment: btw, this is unrelated to Debian. the IANA maintains a list of "well-known ports", which is valid for the whole internet.

Comment: @umläute you are wrong. Not all Debian package ports are IANA "well-known ports". so assuring that my port is not in the IANA list is not enough